# Opening Firefox from terminal

Tags: command-line, firefox, background-process

When I type `firefox` in terminal, it starts Firefox but the terminal "hangs".

What is happening behind the scenes?

Can I open Firefox from terminal and keep on using the same terminal tab for other things without closing Firefox?

Comment: You would have found the solution yourself if you had done a bit of searching. Just put `&` after the command and it will run on background.

Comment: What is happening if I don't put `&`. How would you start firefox from the terminal if you had to and why?

Comment: Well, then the terminal will just hang as you noticed.

Comment: upvote for honest, no nonsense answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The terminal locks when you are running an application from it as long as the application is running. With the ampersand (&) you can start the application in the background and still use the terminal. Type:

```
user@host:~# firefox &
```

To start firefox in the background. Output of the application will still be in the terminal.

Or, if firefox is already running you can do this:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to put firefox into the backgroound.
2. Type:

   ```
   jobs
   ```

   You should see  your jobs like :

   ```
   [1]+  Stopped  firefox.
   ```
3. Type:

   ```
   bg %1
   ```

   (or number of your job)

Comment: Are you running `firefox` as root?

Comment: @MattBianco No, why?

Comment: Traditionally, prompts ending with `#` indicate elevated privileges. (I didn't think you did, btw)

Answer (score 7):

Use `nohup firefox &` to run firefox from terminal and you can use terminal for other process, if you close terminal, firefox will not quit.

If you get error like `Another instance is running` then use `nohup firefox -P --no-remote &` and create a new user profile and browse.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `&` symbol after your command to run it in background.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to run firefox in background as well you can exit the terminal
but still the firefox will run.

```
hussain-->~#nohup firefox &
```

When you simply open the firefox then it will not return the prompt after closing 
the firefox only it will return the prompt.